# "Delete" the € symbol out of every row and keep the rest

Tags: mysql

Good morning!

I have a column (called price) in my table (table1) which has entries like '4,99€', '19,99€' and so on - I only want to "delete" the € symbol out of every row and keep the rest- how can I do it?

I tried it already with update, format and concat - but sth. is wrong. Here´s what I tried so far(MySQL):

```
UPDATE table1 SET price= CONCAT(FORMAT(`price`, 2));
```

Thanks for your support!

PS: The solution of ceyquem works good - so how can I transformate the data format to numbers with commas (so that I can use the sum function)afterwards: I tried it with the following but I got wrong entries in the table with it...?!

```
ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY COLUMN price DEC;
```

Comment: If it's a decimal why you set it as nvarchar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your field is text format, you can do

```
UPDATE table1
   SET price = REPLACE(price ,'€','')
```

Comment: That´s correct and works - how can I transformate the data format to numbers with commas (so that I can use the sum function)afterwards: I tried it with the following but I got wrong entries in the table with it...?!    ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY COLUMN price DEC;

Comment: You are still using a text format field, so you probably need to have dots instead of commas before doing a conversion.

UPDATE table1
   SET price = REPLACE(price ,',','.')

Comment: I did it :) Thanks!

Comment: It´s still not working ( got the same warning as before) :1 223 11:08:47 ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY COLUMN `price` DEC 493537 row(s) affected, 64 warning(s):
 1265 Data truncated for column 'price' at row 1
 1265 Data truncated for column 'price' at row 2
.......                                                                                                   1292 Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '2.215.00 '                            1265 Data truncated for column 'price' at row 49
 ...
 1265 Data truncated for column 'price' at row 104
 Records: 493537  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 33121

Comment: you have also commas used as thousands separators, remove them before replacing the decimal separator.

Comment: Do you really mean commas and not points as thousands separators?